# I can't disable nouveau video driver

Tags: linux, nvidia

My PSU fried my mobo so I transferred my working linux hard drive to another machine with a different video card. I ran a live cd & installed the correct nvidia drivers but it still hangs on boot with

> fb switching to nouveaufb from vesa vga

I blacklisted nouveau but that didn't help either. I've also tried these bootline commands: 
video=nouveaufb:off 
 nomodeset
 nokmsboot
 xforcevesa

In fact safe boot results in kernel panic via

> mount: could not find filesystem '/dev/root'

I even uninstalled nouveau - didn't help. 
Is there any way of making it ignore nouveau & boot normally?

Comment: Hi Joe, StackOverflow is geared towards programming problems rather than general computer use issues which makes your question off-topic here. You will probably have better luck asking a question like this at [Superuser.com](http://superuser.com/) or [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) (if you're using a *buntu distro).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score -1):

I've been dealing with NVidia issues lately. From my experience, the best thing to do when everything is messed up is to delete xorg.conf, uninstall both the NVidia and Nouveau drivers, reinstall Nouveau so you can get Xorg up then fix everything.

A less invasive thing to try would be simply deleting xorg.conf; you would be surprised how often this fixes things.

Also, blacklisting Nouveau in /etc/modprobe.d is the correct thing to do, but not always enough. You might need to blacklist Nouveau in grub. Also double check that all Nouveau junk is gone (especially the Xorg drive).

Can you post your distro, distro version, kernel version, and card info (via lspci)?

Is this a single or multi GPU setup?

Comment: Thanks for your input. It turns out I somehow had a broken boot script and for the record I'm using NVidia drivers like the live cd. I'll have to end this thread now because my system has other unrelated problems.